# gcloud app deploy fails with 7.4 runtime with "requires composer-runtime-api ^2.0.0"

Tags: php, composer-php, gcloud

I've been trying to build a PHP 7.4 app with `gcloud app deploy`, but it fails with:

> Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
> Problem 1
>
> - Installation request for jean85/pretty-package-versions 2.0.4 -> satisfiable by jean85/pretty-package-versions[2.0.4].
> - jean85/pretty-package-versions 2.0.4 requires composer-runtime-api ^2.0.0 -> no matching package found.

This is my `composer.json`:

```
{
  "require": {
    "slim/slim": "^4.0",
    "slim/psr7": "^1.3",
    "slim/http": "^1.2",
    "mongodb/mongodb": "1.5",
    "ext-mongodb": "^1.6",
    "jean85/pretty-package-versions": "^2.0",
    "nesbot/carbon": "^2.52",
    "php-di/php-di": "^6.3",
    "vlucas/phpdotenv": "^5.3"
  },
  "require-dev": {
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.5"   
  }
}
```

*Notes*:

All the information I've found on the Net was about a possible use of Composer 1 instead of Composer 2.

The best I can have about composer on Google App Engine is that when I type composer --version in the interactive console, I get "2.1.6" just like on my local dev environment.

Finally, as evidence, this is the tail of the Cloud Build log:

```
Step #2 - "build": Status: Downloaded newer image for eu.gcr.io/gae-runtimes/buildpacks/php74/builder:php74_20210728_7_4_21_RC00
Step #2 - "build": eu.gcr.io/gae-runtimes/buildpacks/php74/builder:php74_20210728_7_4_21_RC00
Step #2 - "build": Warning: Not restoring or caching layer data, no cache flag specified.
Step #2 - "build": ===> DETECTING
Step #2 - "build": 3 of 4 buildpacks participating
Step #2 - "build": google.php.composer  0.9.1
Step #2 - "build": google.php.appengine 0.9.0
Step #2 - "build": google.utils.label   0.0.1
Step #2 - "build": ===> ANALYZING
Step #2 - "build": Previous image with name "eu.gcr.io/voltaic-plating-324009/app-engine-tmp/app/default/ttl-18h:e941687b-9375-4927-97bb-eecaaf779592" not found
Step #2 - "build": ===> RESTORING
Step #2 - "build": ===> BUILDING
Step #2 - "build": === PHP - Composer (google.php.composer@0.9.1) ===
Step #2 - "build": --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Step #2 - "build": Running "php -r echo PHP_VERSION;"
Step #2 - "build": 7.4.21Done "php -r echo PHP_VERSION;" (378.442053ms)
Step #2 - "build": DEBUG: Current dependency hash: "03f83fc1c2a57c9fa5ba4fe96c867d393f905ed37a0aecd50da328fd8392dae3"
Step #2 - "build": DEBUG:   Cache dependency hash: ""
Step #2 - "build": DEBUG: No metadata found from a previous build, skipping cache.
Step #2 - "build": Installing application dependencies.
Step #2 - "build": DEBUG: ***** CACHE MISS: "prod dependencies"
Step #2 - "build": --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Step #2 - "build": Running "composer install --no-dev --no-progress --no-suggest --no-interaction --optimize-autoloader"
Step #2 - "build": Loading composer repositories with package information
Step #2 - "build": Installing dependencies from lock file
Step #2 - "build": Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
Step #2 - "build": 
Step #2 - "build":   Problem 1
Step #2 - "build":     - Installation request for jean85/pretty-package-versions 2.0.4 -> satisfiable by jean85/pretty-package-versions[2.0.4].
Step #2 - "build":     - jean85/pretty-package-versions 2.0.4 requires composer-runtime-api ^2.0.0 -> no matching package found.
Step #2 - "build": 
Step #2 - "build": Potential causes:
Step #2 - "build":  - A typo in the package name
Step #2 - "build":  - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
Step #2 - "build":    see <https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability> for more details.
Step #2 - "build":  - It's a private package and you forgot to add a custom repository to find it
Step #2 - "build": 
Step #2 - "build": Read <https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common problems.
Step #2 - "build": Done "composer install --no-dev --no-progress --no-suggest --no-in..." (445.718128ms)
Step #2 - "build": Failure: (ID: 467317e4) Loading composer repositories with package information
Step #2 - "build": Installing dependencies from lock file
Step #2 - "build": Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
Step #2 - "build": 
Step #2 - "build":   Problem 1
Step #2 - "build":     - Installation request for jean85/pretty-package-versions 2.0.4 -> satisfiable by jean85/pretty-package-versions[2.0.4].
Step #2 - "build":     - jean85/pretty-package-versions 2.0.4 requires composer-runtime-api ^2.0.0 -> no matching package found.
Step #2 - "build": 
Step #2 - "build": Potential causes:
Step #2 - "build":  - A typo in the package name
Step #2 - "build":  - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
Step #2 - "build":    see <https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability> for more details.
Step #2 - "build":  - It's a private package and you forgot to add a custom repository to find it
Step #2 - "build": 
Step #2 - "build": Read <https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common problems.
```

How can I make sure I have composer 2 within Google Cloud runtime, so I don't get the "requires composer-runtime-api ^2.0.0 -> no  matching package found." error?

Comment: This is a bug on Composer's side. Have a look at this [GitHub issue link](https://github.com/Jean85/pretty-package-versions/issues/40#issuecomment-863011114) and try upgrading Composer to the latest version of 2.1.3 by running `composer self-update 2.1.3`

Comment: @PriyashreeBhadra Latest Composer is 2.1.6, not 2.1.3. And the OP says they have "2.1.16" (which does not exist, and it's likely a typo for "2.1.6"). The bug you mention has been resolved back in June, so it shouldn't be the case here. Your advices would make composer to **downgrade** to a version older than the latest version.

Comment: @yivi you are right but I would like to confirm the composer version as he posted "2.1.16" but we are assuming its 2.1.6 as 2.1.16 does not exist.

Comment: Just letting everyone know that I managed to build the app and connect to an external MongoDB cluster errorfree by using `mongodb/mongodb 1.5`, `ext-mongodb 1.6` and adding a single-line `php.ini` file with `extension=mongodb.so` at the root of my app distro.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/76136736/367456

Answer (score 3):

Currently the runtime images that Google provides have been built before Composer 2 was released (huge hint: latest provided PHP does not include 8.0 yet), so you can't use the Google provided runtimes if you need anything newer than that.

It's bit of a shame that they do no provide newer runtimes or better options, but all hope is not lost.

You can always build your own [custom runtimes](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/php/customizing-the-php-runtime).

The quickest and dirtiest way I can think of having your own custom runtime based on Google's PHP 7.4 but with Composer 2 would be adding a `Dockerfile` alongside your `app.yaml` with the following:

```
FROM gcr.io/google-appengine/php74:latest

RUN composer self-update --2
```

`runtime`, in `app.yaml`, should say: `custom`.

Can't test it right now, but this should get in you the right track.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions @yivi. I can appreciate the custom argument and container registry URI, coming from https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/php/customizing-the-php-runtime. However, when I launch deploy, I receive this: `ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) INVALID_ARGUMENT: Invalid runtime 'custom' specified. Accepted runtimes are: [php, php55, [...] , php72, php73, php74, gcf preprod, gcf prod, gcf staging [...] (truncated to fit)]

Comment: Nevermind, env should be set to `flex`. Was `standard`. I left my previous comment to help others.

Comment: I received this: `Step 1/2 : FROM gcr.io/google-appengine/php74
manifest for gcr.io/google-appengine/php74:latest not found: manifest unknown: Failed to fetch "latest" from request "/v2/google-appengine/php74/manifests/latest".` From then on, the cache is being used. How do you clear the existing image?

Comment: Update: I don't know what changed since last Friday, but the app now builds in std environment, without any hack with composer or jean85 or anything like that. I just kept the two composer.json reference lines about mongodb: the lib, and the extension. The extension seems to be ignored though: the runtime can't find the MongoDB driver for PHP. `Class 'MongoDB\\Driver\\Manager' not found`

Answer (score 2):

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76163427/294171), it appears that you can now specify the Composer version in `app.yaml`:

```yaml
build_env_variables:
  GOOGLE_COMPOSER_VERSION: 2.2.1
```

Answer (score -4):

`requires composer-runtime-api ^2.0.0` can be solved pretty easy: run `composer install` with Composer v2, not with any older version. Reading that version is possible through calling `composer diagnose`. All further steps to debug the problem can be found on the [page that is linked in the error message](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md)

Comment: Nico, just letting you know that I, at first sight, I haven't got the choice of composer version, since the later is imposed by Google App Engine. However, @yivi asked me to try a trick, which I will when I have a chance, and I'll give my feedback here.